# Multi-Select File Dialog Issue

Tags: vba, openfiledialog, autodesk

So...I'm fairly certain I'm just missing something really simple, but I'm not seeing anything online. I have a file dialog in which I need to select multiple files. Seems simple enough. I can select multiple files using "oFileDlg.MultiSelectEnabled = True", but when I accept my selected files that post in to the listbox, only one shows up. I believe that what it's doing is concatenating the file names in to one long line, but I'm not sure how to separate them. Any tips or help would be very much appreciated!!!

Code:

```
Private Sub cmdSourceAdd_Click()
Dim oFileDlg As FileDialog
' Create a new FileDialog object.
Call ThisApplication.CreateFileDialog(oFileDlg)

' Define the filter to select part and assembly files or any file.
oFileDlg.Filter = "Inventor Files (*.iam;*.ipt;*.idw;*.dwg)|*.iam;*.ipt;*.idw;*.dwg|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
' Define the part and assembly files filter to be the default filter.
oFileDlg.FilterIndex = 1
oFileDlg.MultiSelectEnabled = True

' Set the title for the dialog.
oFileDlg.DialogTitle = "Open File Test"

' Set the initial directory that will be displayed in the dialog.
'oFileDlg.InitialDirectory = ThisApplication.FileOptions.ProjectsPath

' Set the flag so an error will be raised if the user clicks the Cancel button.
oFileDlg.CancelError = True

' Show the open dialog.  The same procedure is also used for the Save dialog.
' The commented code can be used for the Save dialog.
On Error Resume Next
oFileDlg.ShowOpen
'    oFileDlg.ShowSave

' If an error was raised, the user clicked cancel, otherwise display the filename.
If Err Then
    MsgBox "User cancelled out of dialog"
ElseIf Not oFileDlg.fileName = "" Then
    lstSource.AddItem oFileDlg.fileName
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When using `multiselect` you get an array of filenames - you need to loop through that array.  Is this for AutoDesk? - you should probably add that tag if so.

Comment: I did :) And thank you! I'm working on that now. I accidentally created an endless loop :O hahaha this is gonna be fun to figure out

Comment: I tried:
    `Do Until oFileDlg.fileName = "" 
    Loop`

But it's endless because it's not actually going to the next file. How can I get it to select the next file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AutoDesk, and it seems it works quite differently from Office VBA, so there's not much I can offer.  From a little Googling it looks like when you use multiselect `fileName` is returned as a string which contains the file names concatenated with `|` so you can try using `Split(fileName,"|")` to create an array you can loop through.

Comment: That's it! I couldn't figure out how exactly to set it up. Rodney Thomas from Jaytek Development helped me out. Answer is posted below :)

Answer (score 0):

Shout out to Rodney Thomas from Jaytek Development for the solution!

```
ElseIf Not oFileDlg.fileName = "" Then
    Dim fNames As Variant
    fNames = Split(oFileDlg.fileName, "|")
    Dim curName As Variant
    For Each curName In fNames
        lstSource.AddItem curName
    Next curName
End If
```